# pywinauto with Remote Desktop

Tags: python, remote-desktop, rdp, pywinauto

I have just started to use the pywinauto module to automate GUI tasks. One of them is to launch the remote desktop exe (mstsc.exe)->Login->Invoke another tool there.

However, I manged to connect to the remote server but the control gets lost after that. I did not manage to login. So, the question is how to use the pywinauto with Remote Desktop? Has any one tried this before?

Answer (score 1):

After trying out various things I figured that the window which opens after pressing the "Connect" button on mstsc can be found by searching for the window with the title 'XYZ - Remote Desktop' where XYZ is the name of the remote server. I have tested this on the WinXP.